# How can I make a title fade?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I've made something like in this gif:

[image: gif]

But the only thing missing part is the Fading Title, which I don't know how it can be done.

I think that I need to know the position of the scroll, so that at a certain position, if the user keeps scrolling, then the Title keeps fading until it disappears. i'm not sure, maybe there is another way, any ideas?

Here's what I've got so far:

```
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  body: SafeArea(
    child: CustomScrollView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverAppBar(
          primary: false,
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          expandedHeight: 300.0,
          //
          centerTitle: true,
          flexibleSpace: Center(
            child: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              centerTitle: true,
              titlePadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 20, 135),
              collapseMode: CollapseMode.none,
              title: Text(
                'Set Up Your Profile',
                style: TextStyle(
                color: kAppPurple,
                fontFamily: 'NotoSans',
                fontSize: 25,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(...),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check this link.

[Flutter: Increase the power of your AppBar & SliverAppBar](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-increase-the-power-of-your-appbar-sliverappbar-c4f67c4e076f)

The Sample 2 is something you want to achieve but he is doing it with an image.

It covers exactly what you want though.

**This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I26rzdjqVXA) gives you a walkthrough on how to achieve it!**

Answer (score 1):

You should put the title in the background property of flexibleSpaceBar, then it will fade away automatically as you collapse the AppBar.